# After update to 18.04 applications constantly freeze

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 18.04, freeze, nvidia-geforce

I recently updated from 17.10 to 18.04.

After the upgrade I've noticed that desktop applications constantly, randomly lock up. This happens about once every minute. The constant random freezes last from about 1 second to 20 seconds.

This issue makes my computer unusable as a work desktop.

I've got a relatively powerful computer: it has an i7 and 16Gb of RAM. So the issue can't be from lack of resources.

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

Returns VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] (rev a1)

I understand that this is a relatively good video processor, so I don't expect issues there either.

What could be causing the freezes? How do I prevent them?

Comment: Do you have any errors displayed?  Does `dmesg` output look like it has anything useful to add to the question?

Comment: I can't see any obvious screams of terror in the output of dmesg: https://hastebin.com/ukibefozof.go

Comment: How much RAM? How much Swap? `free;swapon` will show you.

Comment: @waltinator: I've got 16gb of RAM. 'free -m' show the following output:  https://hastebin.com/nuqoculuhu.cpp

Comment: I have this same issue on a fresh install of 18.04 with nvidia-390 and a gt 650m (rMBP early-2013)

Comment: I have this same issue, with a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation, AMD Threadripper, ASUS Strix x399 and nVidia graphics card (tried GTX 550Ti and 750 Ti). Any help to diagnose the problem, please?

Answer (score 1):

I had same behavior as described here (fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on a new computer). I feared some hardware issue between the cpu (AMD Threadripper), the mainboard (ASUS x399) and the video driver (tried with Nvidia GTX 250, GTX 550Ti and GTX 750 Ti, nothing changed).

Then, today I updated Chrome to the last stable version, 68.0. All freezes and hangups are now gone. Hope this can help someone.

Comment: After a new Chrome update, hung ups returned! Can someone give some hints on how to debug this issue, please?